# Apply transformation/data augmentation to single image with Pytorch

Tags: python-3.x, image, image-processing, deep-learning, pytorch

I am training my Pytorch Image classification Model with Pytorch on GPU and i am trying data augmentation exercise on single images. But I am getting various errors because:

1. My image tensors are on GPU and not accessible via CPU
2. Invalid shape if I read a single image directly and apply transformations to it.

First Apoproach:

```
def Show_Image(Image, Picture_Name):
    plt.imshow(Image)
    plt.title(Picture_Name)
    plt.show()

#train_dl is my training dataloader
data_iter = iter(train_dl)
images , label = next(data_iter)
test_image = images[0]
test_image = test_image.to(device)

Horizontal_Flipping_Transformation = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.ToPILImage()
])

Flipping_Img = Horizontal_Flipping_Transformation(test_image)
Show_Image(test_image, 'Original Image')
Show_Image(Flipping_Img, 'Flipped Image')
```

**Error**:

```
TypeError: can't convert cuda:0 device type tensor to numpy. Use Tensor.cpu() to copy the tensor to host memory first.
```

Second approach:

```
from torchvision.io import read_image
img = read_image(r'baboon\n02486410_1.JPEG')

def Show_Image(Image, Picture_Name):
    plt.imshow(Image)
    plt.title(Picture_Name)
    plt.show()

#Horizontal Flipping Transformation
Horizontal_Flipping_Transformation = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToPILImage(),
    transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip(),
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.ToPILImage()
])

Flipping_Img = Horizontal_Flipping_Transformation(img)
Show_Image(test_image, 'Original Image')
Show_Image(Flipping_Img, 'Flipped Image')
```

**Error**:    `TypeError: Invalid shape (3, 64, 64) for image data`

How do we apply transformations to a single image and display the results via Pytorch?
I am able to do this If I apply directly to my base class when I am reading the data itself but not able to do it separately.
I need to understand where I am going wrong and the snippet of code to correct it?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to apply something like [torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop](https://pytorch.org/vision/main/generated/torchvision.transforms.RandomResizedCrop.html) first to resize/crop the images to the right size.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this my making two changes:

```
def Show_Image(Image, Picture_Name):
    plt.imshow(Image)
    plt.title(Picture_Name)
```

and

```
Show_Image(img.permute(1, 2, 0), 'Original Image')
```